# Inserting Foreign Language Characters in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I currently use `htmlentities` to insert data into MySQL. I was just wondering if there is a better, or more efficient, way -- one that would take up less space.

Would this affect searching my database?

Would `utf8_general_ci` be OK to use for all languages?

Which is best: `htmlspecialchars` or `htmlentities`?

Comment: utf-8 is fine for all languages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you should store the raw data in the database (utf8_general_ci is fine), and **only use functions like [htmlentities](http://us.php.net/htmlentities) at the very last minute** before outputting the information to the browser.